# Getting subset of QSet limited by non-existent elements

Tags: c++, qt

I need to store QSet[QTime] (or similar) data. The thing that i want to do is to get subset of elements in range , where A and B may not exist i.e.

vector[int] 5 7 9 11 13
range ( 6, 11) => 7 9 11

Is it possible? Maybe there is better way of doing that?
Thanks for advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution would be `std::set<QTime>`. It is ordered, and offers `lower_bound` and `upper_bound` methods. These do not require that the actual bounds are present in the set.

Comment: +1 for new-to-me fact...though I will mention that the Qt collection classes in a holistically Qt-based project offer several different features over the standard library.  One of the most relevant to my codebases is thread-safe implicit sharing: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/implicit-sharing.html

Comment: Implicit sharing has proven to be a burden in multi-threaded applications. It's better to have multiple independent copies than a single, contended copy. Memory is cheap, synchronization isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to write code to do that, but `QSet` is an "unordered" collection, with no particularly efficient operation for doing what you ask.  You pretty much have to enumerate them and test each element to see if it qualifies:

```
QSet<QTime> set;
QTime earliest = QTime::fromString("1.30", "m.s");
QTime latest = QTime::fromString("10.30", "m.s");
...
QSet<QTime> subset;
QSetIterator<QTime> i (set);
while (i.hasNext()) {
    QTime t = i.next();
    if ((t >= earliest) && (t <= latest)) {
        subset.insert(t);
    }
}
```

If that's not fast enough for your purposes you'll have to use different data structures and techniques.  And if you want your subset to be sorted then you'll need to store it in an ordered collection, but then I wouldn't really call it a "subset" but something more like a "subrange" or a "slice".  (The word "set" in computer science usually implies that the order of elements is not interesting for the application...but @MSalters has pointed out that `std::set` *does* have order, which was news to me!)

Comment: The word "set" in computer science is rather unrelated to `std::set` in C++, which explicitly is ordered (as oppposed to `std::unordered_set`)

Comment: std::set has order?  Every "set" I've ever seen elsewhere did not guarantee order.  STL is not something I've used enough to have noticed this...I'd have expected them to call them "ordered_set" and "set".  Thanks for pointing this out, I will look into their reasoning.

Comment: Yes, it's even a template parameter: `template <class Key, class Compare = less<Key>> class set`. I.e. the default is ascending, but `set<int, greater<int>>` is in descending order.

Comment: Wikipedia's article on set starts out with what I've always thought the term was supposed to mean, with *"In computer science, a set is an abstract data structure that can store certain values, without any particular order, and no repeated values."* and then goes on to say C++ `std::set` has order.  No explanation of why...do you know?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28computer_science%29

Comment: That's just WP; I can't be bothered to fix it. Obviously wrong.